# How to display the image from the same web source without using url?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently, I am building a form (similar to google forms) using my company's website. I want to display an image and the image source is from the same website so there's no URL but instead an id. The position of the images is at the top while I want it wrapping the text.

```
<div class="info-row">
    <div class="info-label">EVALUATE RESULTS, PROCESSES AND STANDARDIZATION:</div>
    <div class="info-value">{{ id }}</div>
    <div input type="image">{{ id }}</div>
    <img src="/image/id" max-width="100" height="auto" alt="attachment"</div> 
</div>
```

**What I want**

PROBLEM STATEMENT:

(image)

(text)

EVALUATE RESULTS, PROCESSES, AND STANDARDIZATION:

(image)

(text)

**What I have now**

(image)

(image)

PROBLEM STATEMENT:

(text)

EVALUATE RESULTS, PROCESSES, AND STANDARDIZATION:

(text)

Comment: Share here what is the position of the image in relation to the code you attached here?

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking additional questions, and edit this question to make it appropriate for Stackoverflow. We don't know what you're referring to when you say "widget" nor what happens when someone "submits the form."

Comment: Replace "how do i..." with "How to...". Remove unnecessary information like "i am a beginniner...". Remove unnecessary prefacing like "It doesn't work and I have no idea what to change" and instead go straight into what you're wanting to happen, what you're doing, and what error you're getting. It is important that you put effort into writing easy to read questions that follow Stack Overflow etiquette if you want people to put in effort answering.

Comment: You are not currectly closing the second-to-last div tag. You have `/div>` instead of `</div>`

Comment: On the website, I just use the existing feature. Ex: 'Attached File' feature. When I add this feature to the form, it will have its unique ID (Ex: Y5WC). After the user click submits, the data will be saved on the same web but different page. The display of the data is as what I have written above @HaimAbeles

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have changed it but still not working. I suspect it's related to the image source @MichaelMoreno

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

You could try and put the image you are trying to display in a wwwroot file if you have one in the software your using to build this I had a problem similar to this in a asp.net app and doing that fixed it so it could be a solution you need

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).